# Wifi occasionally stalls

Tags: wifi

I've had some trouble getting good wifi performance out of my Pi, but after lots of googling and trying things I get about 2.5Mbit/s and a median ping of about 230ms.

Not great, but tolerable.

Except that the AVERAGE ping is over 1000ms, simply because every few minutes the wifi completely stalls for a few seconds, creating pings with up to 12000ms (but no package loss).

I've already added a seperate power supply to the wifi-dongle (with a USB Y cable) and added `options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf` which should disable the powersaving mode, but it seems the Pi still sends the dongle to sleep every so often.

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT: I confused MB and Mbit, oops ^^"

EDIT 2: lsusb output: `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7822 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd`

EDIT 3/4: uname -a output: `Linux zehnvorne 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`
Debian version `8.0`

Comment: Wifi issues are VERY often directly related to the specific device, thus you should include the USB ID (xxxx:xxxx) of your device. With `lsusb` you can request a list of connected USB devices, which also includes the USB ID (but better yet, post the whole line of your device).

Comment: According to http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2014-04-07-edimax-ew-7612uan-wifi-usb-adapter-300mbits-802-11n the driver is not included in the kernel. Where did you get your driver from? Also include that info in your question, not in a comment ;-)
Other useful info is what distribution and version you're using and the kernel (`uname -a`)

Comment: That information is very old and - since I didn't install any drivers - apparently outdated.

Comment: That's entirely possible :-) Can you include the whole output of `uname -a` as that gives more info then just 4.1.7? Can you also include the version of raspbian (`cat /etc/debian_version`) ?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add `rtw_ips_mode=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf` ?

Comment: I'll check it once I'm back at the office. Which is on Tuesday. Sorry to leave you hanging ;)

Comment: Adding `rtw_ips_mode=0` does indeed make notable difference. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent and good to know :)

Comment: I've added it as a answer as that's way more visible then these comments and that also explains how I got to that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason disabling power management at compile time and at runtime, through `options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0` still does not result in the same behavior. In `drivers/net/wireless/rtl8192cu/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c` you can find the following code block:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_POWER_SAVING
int rtw_power_mgnt = 1;
#ifdef CONFIG_IPS_LEVEL_2
int rtw_ips_mode = IPS_LEVEL_2;
#else
int rtw_ips_mode = IPS_NORMAL;
#endif
#else
int rtw_power_mgnt = PS_MODE_ACTIVE;
int rtw_ips_mode = IPS_NONE;
#endif
```

Thus setting `rtw_ips_mode=0` (0=IPS_NONE) besides `rtw_power_mgnt=0` (0=PS_MODE_ACTIVE) should fix that.